# How to downgrade keras and tensorflow version on windows?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, versions

i'm trying to run a code which i found on the internet called FgSegNet, the code writer mention that he uses Python 3.6.3, Keras 2.0.6,and Tensorflow-gpu 1.1.0.
and i'm using, anaconda3, python 3.5.5, keras 2.1.6,and tensorflow 1.8.0. on windows.
i'm new with python and stuff, plz tell me, should I downgrade keras and tensorflow? and how?
thanks in advance

Comment: Just create a new environment in Anaconda and install the versions you need. You can then switch between the environments without having to downgrade.

Comment: Do you want to know "if" of "how"? I think you should first try without downgrading, if problems appear, then you try to downgrade.

Comment: thank you guys i think the answer of @Surya Tej will work

Comment: How can I do this with conda?

Answer (score -1):

create a requirement.txt file with your required packages

```
Keras=2.0.6
tensorflow-gpu<=1.1.0
```

open an anaconda prompt

```
conda create -n NewEnv python=3.6.3
```

once the new environment is created , use pip to install dependencies

```
pip install -r <full path>/requirements.txt
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you @Surya Tej, i'll try that. hope it will work

Comment: it doesn't work, when I run the code there is an error pumped up says "No module named 'numpy' ", I tryed to install numpy but an other error appears " No module named 'tansorflow' ".... an so on. PS: I didn't faced these errors when I created the first env (which has keras 2.1.6,and tensorflow 1.8.0). could you plz give me any idea to solve this?

Comment: Just a question, have you activated the correct environment? also just try opening python prompt in anaconda environment and import numpy, to see if you are still facing the same error.. it could be mostly due to loading package from different paths issue

Comment: yes, I'm in the correct env, and i tried with anaconda prompt and the error always the same!

Comment: just one more question, have you installed the packages, (i mean keras, tensorflow-gpu) after creating a new environment, activating it and then pip install them right?

Comment: yeah I did that!